# Can't deploy Google Cloud Datalab - Application in non-US zone

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I've selected my Google API project 4 times now and pushed ["Deploy DataLab"](https://datalab.cloud.google.com/), but whenever I check back I have no Datalab project.

The last time I had the following error message, but I have billing enabled, am the owner and the BigQuery/Google Compute Engine APIs are activated.

[image]

Checking the logs it says I'm in the wrong region:

```
Oct 13 19:42:35 datalab-deploy-main-20151013-19-40-34 startupscript: Pushing tag for rev [b886390e822d] on {https://gcr.io/v1/repositories/_m_sdk/mark-edmondson-gde.datalab.main/tags/latest}
Oct 13 19:42:36 datalab-deploy-main-20151013-19-40-34 startupscript: 07:42 PM Host: appengine.google.com
Oct 13 19:42:36 datalab-deploy-main-20151013-19-40-34 startupscript: 07:42 PM Application: mark-edmondson-gde (was: None); module: datalab; version: main (was: None)
Oct 13 19:42:36 datalab-deploy-main-20151013-19-40-34 startupscript: 07:42 PM 
Oct 13 19:42:36 datalab-deploy-main-20151013-19-40-34 startupscript: Starting update of app: mark-edmondson-gde, module: datalab
Oct 13 19:42:36 datalab-deploy-main-20151013-19-40-34 startupscript: 07:42 PM Getting current resource limits.
Oct 13 19:42:36 datalab-deploy-main-20151013-19-40-34 startupscript: 07:42 PM Scanning files on local disk.
Oct 13 19:42:37 datalab-deploy-main-20151013-19-40-34 startupscript: Error 400: --- begin server output ---
Oct 13 19:42:37 datalab-deploy-main-20151013-19-40-34 startupscript: Managed VMs can not be hosted in the application's region.
Oct 13 19:42:37 datalab-deploy-main-20151013-19-40-34 startupscript: --- end server output ---
Oct 13 19:42:37 datalab-deploy-main-20151013-19-40-34 startupscript: ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Command failed with error code [1]
Oct 13 19:42:37 datalab-deploy-main-20151013-19-40-34 startupscript: Step deploy datalab module failed.
```

Comment: Hi Mark - did you take a look at the logs? They should give an indication of why the deployer failed.

Comment: I see the logs now, and see the issue - I'm in the wrong region :(.  Will add to question.

Comment: Hi Mark ... currently managed VMs are in beta and only supported in the US. Investigating if its possible to force creation of Datalab even if your project is associated with a European region (my guess). Any chance you have an alternate project associated with a US region in the meantime?

Comment: Thanks, the problem is my nice BigQuery data is in a EU database :)  But I can at least take a look with a US project, thanks.  May I suggest that this requirement is mentioned on the startup screen too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently managed VMs are in beta and only supported in the US.

Investigating if its possible to override the zone setting when deploying Datalab.

Comment: Thanks. It would be nice to improve error messaging (currently it stops silently without telling you why)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, at this point, cloud projects created with non-US (i.e. "europe-west") App Engine location do not allow managed VM deployment. There is no override available as of now to deploy to a US-based location where managed VMs are available. A workaround would be to create another project and grant access to relevant data to the App Engine service account.
Apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: are there plans to fix this? Legally it's very hard to process data in the US at the moment due to Safe Harbor issues