# Can not deploy Google Cloud Datalab - no logs

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I tried deploying Google Cloud Datalab, but for some reason it didnt do anything
the progress bar is stuck, and the log file just returns "Not Found"

Comment: So, the program bar is finished, but when launching the data lab, theres no sample project

Answer (score 2):

The log file creation can lag by about ten seconds from the link appearing. If you refresh your browser periodically you should see the log appear.

Comment: Small note -- refresh the log tab, not the deployer tab.

Comment: Still nothing in the logs. the project did get deployed in the end but I dont have any sample project in it. any way to get it?

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, the log file gets generated into Cloud Storage within your project in a bucket named:

[project-id]-datalab

If you browse to that in the Developer Console, you should see a /logs folder with a timestamp-based log file.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Datalab is only supported in projects based in the US region. One possible cause of a failure to launch is that your project is in another region (i.e. Europe).

See: [Can't deploy Google Cloud Datalab - Application in non-US zone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33114405/55469)

Comment: I'm not using ManagedVM's so I think this is not relevant?

Comment: I'm not sure that matters. If you've specified the Europe region when you created your project, then Datalab won't deploy as it's only currently supported in US-region projects.

Answer (score -1):

Its just broken.
The logs only seem to work with a Chrome Browser ( which is a laugh as usually Firefox is better at running google apps than chrome)
So try and delpoy from Chrome and the log link should work afetr about 10 seconds