# Deploying Google Cloud Datalab fails with "Not enough VMs ready"

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I changed to a new project after I had an [issue with a non-US project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33110656/cant-deploy-google-cloud-datalab-application-in-non-us-zone) but now I have a different error problem.

I'm now in a us-east project zone, billing enabled.

The issue this time is detailed in the logs here:

```
Oct 18 10:43:59 datalab-deploy-main-20151018-10-34-58 startupscript: 10:43 AM Not enough VMs ready (0/1 ready, 1 still deploying). Deployed Version: datalab:main.387933421330143384
Oct 18 10:43:59 datalab-deploy-main-20151018-10-34-58 startupscript: ERROR: Not enough VMs ready (0/1 ready, 1 still deploying). Deployed Version: datalab:main.387933421330143384
Oct 18 10:43:59 datalab-deploy-main-20151018-10-34-58 startupscript: 10:43 AM Rolling back the update.  This can sometimes take a while since a VM version is being rolled back.
Oct 18 10:44:00 datalab-deploy-main-20151018-10-34-58 startupscript: Could not start serving the given version.
Oct 18 10:44:00 datalab-deploy-main-20151018-10-34-58 startupscript: ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Command failed with error code [1]
Oct 18 10:44:00 datalab-deploy-main-20151018-10-34-58 startupscript: Step deploy datalab module failed.
```

I tried again after a few weeks, still got the same error.  Here are the logs:

```
    Nov 10 10:01:10 datalab-deploy-main-20151110-09-59-21 startupscript: If this is your first deployment, this may take a while...#015If this is your first deployment, this may take a while.../#015If this is your first deployment, this may take a while...-#015If this is your first deployment, this may take a while...\#015If this is your first deployment, this may take a while...|#015If this is your first deployment, this may take a while...done.
    Nov 10 10:01:10 datalab-deploy-main-20151110-09-59-21 startupscript: 
    Nov 10 10:01:10 datalab-deploy-main-20151110-09-59-21 startupscript: Building and pushing image for module [datalab]
    Nov 10 10:01:49 datalab-deploy-main-20151110-09-59-21 startupscript: Updating module [datalab]...#015
Updating module [datalab].../#015
Updating module [datalab]...-#015
Updating module [datalab]...\#015
Updating module [datalab]...|#015
Updating module [datalab].../#015
Updating module [datalab]...-#015
```

repeated lots and lots until finally...

```
startupscript: ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Not enough VMs ready (0/1 ready, 1 still deploying). Version: datalab:main.388466283677388941
Nov 10 10:08:22 datalab-deploy-main-20151110-09-59-21 startupscript: Step deploy datalab module failed.
```

Trying again in a totally fresh new project I now get a permissions error:

```
Nov 10 21:48:41 datalab-deploy-main-20151110-21-42-57 startupscript: Verifying that Managed VMs are enabled and ready.
Nov 10 21:48:41 datalab-deploy-main-20151110-21-42-57 startupscript: If this is your first deployment, this may take a while...#015If this is your first deployment, this may take a while...done.
Nov 10 21:48:41 datalab-deploy-main-20151110-21-42-57 startupscript: WARNING: If this is your first deployment, please try again.
Nov 10 21:48:41 datalab-deploy-main-20151110-21-42-57 startupscript: ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Server responded with code [403]:
Nov 10 21:48:41 datalab-deploy-main-20151110-21-42-57 startupscript:   Forbidden Unexpected HTTP status 403.
Nov 10 21:48:41 datalab-deploy-main-20151110-21-42-57 startupscript:   You do not have permission to modify this app (app_id=u's~random-bananas-111111').
Nov 10 21:48:42 datalab-deploy-main-20151110-21-42-57 startupscript: Step deploy datalab module failed.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the suggestions here helped, but after the 4th new project and attempting to deploy again, persistence proved to be the answer and it worked :)

Comment: Apologies for the trouble. We are working to improve deployment experience and understand that having to retry and then encounter the transient error again is frustrating. Thanks for trying multiple times.
(PM for Cloud Datalab)

Comment: Thanks Dinesh, typical it starts to work when you take a look, I attribute some of its success to your observation ;)

Answer (score 1):

For this issue: "You do not have permission to modify this app..", go to permissions and recreate the XXXXX-compute@... account. This works for me.

For the original issue: "Not enough VMs ready", I had to recreate the project and tried again. Finally got it to go.

Answer (score 0):

The "not enough VMs ready" might have been a transient error. Could you retry, and see if you get further?

Thanks...

Comment: I tried it again, got the same error.  Added the logs from that attempt.

Answer (score 0):

It might be caused by a permissions issue and might have been fixed recently. Could you give it another try? If it still fails with the same error, try the following:

1. Go to Developer Console, Permissions, under "Service Accounts", find the account [project-id]@appspot.gserviceaccount.com.
2. Copy the account id to somewhere else since we'll use it later. Then remove the account from the list, make sure it disappears from the list, and add it back with "Can edit" permission.
3. Wait for a few minutes and try deploying Datalab again.

The issue is probably project specific so if possible, you may also try Datalab in a new project.

Let me know how it goes!

Comment: I now get a different error regarding permissions, updated the post :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend going to **Operations > Logging** and select "crash.log" and "any level" for the version you tried to deploy to. You'll get a massive dump of unorganized logs, but there will most likely be an error in there that prevented your container from being built.

Yes, the error message is entirely unhelpful, but the logs should capture an issue that caused the container to fail.

If this doesn't work, try running the containers locally using docker and make sure it builds.